# Padding-Right or Padding-Left problem when direction change between RTL and LTR in a table

Tags: html, padding, right-to-left

I'm developing a project in two languages (RTL and LTR) so when I design my tables some TDs must have right or left padding and I when I changes page direction to other, left padding means right and vies-versa and it is my problem because I shoud design my table once for RTl and once for LTR.

My problem:

```
LTR                  RTL
```

|  Hello|    ---->     |  سلام|

that correct design:

|  Hello|    ---->     |سلام  |

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you have two options.

**One.** create classes for specific directional text and style accordingly.  So

`<td class="rtl"></td>`

and the css

```
td.rtl{
    direction:rtl;
    padding-left:20px;  //OR WHATEVER
}
```

And then the opposite for `ltr`

**Two.** set the padding one way. Then use jQuery to detect the direction and adjust accordingly.

So something like

```
$('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('direction') == 'rtl'){
        $(this).css({'padding-left':'//whatver','padding-right':'0'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with **Pure CSS**

instead of using `left` or `right` use `*-inline-start` and `*-inline-end`

```css
.ltr { /*default not required*/ }
.rtl { direction: rtl; }

.myClass {
  padding-inline-end: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #222
}
```

```html
<span class="myClass ltr"> Hello </span>
<hr/>
<span class="myClass rtl"> سلام </span>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start